# Why adding a relationship breaks my view?

Tags: organic-groups, views

I have a Drupal 7.26 site with the latest Organic Groups module. Every user of the site will be in one group, and one group only. My groups have two different group content types -- schools and classrooms -- and both of these group content types are private, i.e. users can only see the nodes that belong to their group.

It's important to note that classrooms are tied to schools via an entity reference field, and that each classroom has an integer field for the number of students in the classroom.

I created a view that will display a table listing all of the schools that belong to the group, and total number of classrooms per school. This works: Users can only view this table in the group that they belong to.
However, I want to add one more column to this table: total number of students in the partner. To do this, I have to add a "classroom" relationship to the view, since the number of students is an integer field on the classroom node, not the school node, so it's one level deeper.

When I do this, the table will only show schools which the user created/authored. Without that relationship, the user can see ALL of the schools in the group, even ones they didn't create, which is what I want.

Why adding the classroom relationship to my view restricts the output to the content types the user authored?